# Bluestacks Cordova Application Chrome Debugging

Tags: android, cordova, google-chrome-devtools, bluestacks

I Have build my hybrid application using cordova, generated APK, and installed it on my blustacks emulator.

The question is how to debug this application using chrome inspector ?

Comment: Use Genymotion instead that does support Chrome Debugger.

Comment: Hi! Were you able to solve in the end?

Comment: @LppEdd this was asked long time back, so I dont remember. However let me know what you are trying to do, maybe I can help.

Comment: @ProllyGeek Oh don't worry, I have solved. I've just connected to the physical device with the app in debug mode :)

Answer (score 1):

I'm now working on Cordova project and use NetBeans + Chrome inspect for debugging. Running projects from NetBeans in android emulator(from SDK) you can easily connect with `chrome://inspect`. NetBeans is good for debugging native-side elements while Chrome inspect is pretty good in logging nested javascript objects.

Answer (score 0):

Chrome debugging needs adb, be sure it's started with:

```
adb kill-server
adb start-server
```

(tested with bluestacks)